# How can I simplify this find command that has too many -o's?

Tags: regex, linux, shell

```sh
find . "$HOME"/Documents -iname *.md -o -iname *.html -o -iname *.css -o -iname *.js -o -iname *.ts -o -iname *.txt
```

I can't find a way to get rid of all these many crufty `-o -iname`'s and have something like `*.{md,html}`. It needs to be one statement.

Bonus round question... how can I exclude `node_modules` from the search :)?

Comment: Bonus question: `-path node_modules -prune`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-iregex` option that allows alternation:

```
find "$HOME"/Documents -regextype awk -iregex '.*\.(md|html|css|js|ts|txt)'
```